# How can I send an asychronous WCF call?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a call to my WCF service asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400798/how-to-make-a-call-to-my-wcf-service-asynchronous)

Here is how I am doing it

```
Dim wcfService = New EmailBlastService.EmailBlastServiceClient
wcfService.WCFSubCallAsync()
```

But when I actually do the call it seems to tie up the server for about a minute (even though I know the async process takes longer than that and is still processing the request). Even if I try to hit the page in a different browser it still takes a minute to load.

Basically I just want to make the WCF call and forget about it, I don't want users to be waiting while I am doing some heavy processing and calling an external

Answer (score 2):

This can help you -

[How to make a call to my WCF service asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400798/how-to-make-a-call-to-my-wcf-service-asynchronous)