# wcf oneway non blocking operation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-endpoint

I need such scenario: client sends message to server, not waiting for response, and don't care, if message was send properly.

```
using(host.RemoteService client = new host.RemoteService())
{
client.Open();

cliend.SendMessage("msg");
}
```

in scenario when firewall is on, or there is no connection to the internet, client dies at "SendMessage". I mean program stops to respond. I wish program don't care about the result. I mean if there is no connection, i wish program to go further, omitting "SendMessage" or sth like that.

What should I do, is there any solution for non blocking method?

Comment: Edited my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this in your service contract:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
void Send(string message);
```

See the following link:

[One Way Operation in WCF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/one-way-operation-in-wcf/)

Edit: OP was already using my suggested solution.

Suggested approaches to solve the issue - taken from MSDN ([One-Way Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

> ### Clients Blocking with One-Way Operations
>
> It is important to realize that while some one-way applications return
>   as soon as the outbound data is written to the network connection, in
>   several scenarios the implementation of a binding or of a service can
>   cause a WCF client to block using one-way operations. In WCF client
>   applications, the WCF client object does not return until the outbound
>   data has been written to the network connection. **This is true for
>   all message exchange patterns, including one-way operations; this
>   means that any problem writing the data to the transport prevents the
>   client from returning**. Depending upon the problem, the result could
>   be an exception or a delay in sending messages to the service.
>
> You can mitigate some of this problem by inserting a buffer between
>   the client object and the client transport's send operation. For
>   example, **using asynchronous calls or using an in-memory message
>   queue can enable the client object to return quickly**. Both
>   approaches may increase functionality, but the size of the thread pool
>   and the message queue still enforce limits.
>
> It is recommended, instead, that you examine the various controls on
>   the service as well as on the client, and then test your application
>   scenarios to determine the best configuration on either side. For
>   example, if the use of sessions is blocking the processing of messages
>   on your service, you can set the
>   `System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode`
>   property to `PerCall` so that each message can be processed by a
>   different service instance, and set the `ConcurrencyMode` to
>   `Multiple` in order to allow more than one thread to dispatch messages
>   at a time. Another approach is to increase the read quotas of the
>   service and client bindings.

Comment: " using asynchronous calls " means like trying to connect to endpoint from different thread or sth like that? Sorry for dummy question I'm quite new to WCF

Comment: Try what's written in the 3rd paragraph first - set the System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode property to PerCall (...), and set the ConcurrencyMode to Multiple

Comment: @santBart: This may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400798/how-to-make-a-call-to-my-wcf-service-asynchronous

Comment: I was wondering if I can use sth like "client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);" when it works ok it takes 2 seconds to send, in case of exception "The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:00:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout." it lasts 8 seconds.  I am looking for possibly easiest solution.

Comment: @santBart: in my answer you can find different approaches to solve your problem, now it's up to you to try them till you find one that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your attribute

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
```

Comment: It has already such atribute.

ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)

OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)